# Simple PHP Login Form Returns '0' mysqli_num_rows. What's wrong with my code logic?

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication

Trying to create simple PHP login form that takes 'username' and 'password', if matched with `'dbusername'` and `'dbpassword`' the code should `echo "You're Logged In!.`

When I run the code, I get no errors.The page goes from `login.php` to `process.php` but shows a blank page. Doesn't show: echo "Incorrent username or password!" or "You're Logged In!".

I checked to see if its returning any rows from database. I'm getting 0 rows. But why?! Is my code logic incorrect? Because my database connection works AND I have a `username: alex and password: abc` in my database named `phplogin` and in table `users`

```
   <?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'phplogin';

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT *
                      FROM users
                      WHERE username = '".$username."'
                      AND password = '".$password."'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo mysqli_num_rows($result); //   I Checked to see if I was getting no rows. *I am getting 0 rows!!* But why?!


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $dbusername = $row['username'];
        $dbpassword = $row['password'];

        //check to see if the match

if($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword ) {

        echo "You're Logged In!";

 } if($username != $dbusername || $password != $dbpassword) {
        echo "Incorrect password or username!";
} else {
        die("That user doesn't exist!");
}

}

}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**Here is my login.php page [form]**

```
<html>

    <form action="process.php" method="POST">
    Username:   <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Password:   <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In"><br>

</html>
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1:** The issue was with my variables conflicting with database.

Now I am getting the following once I login and it has to do with the last statement on my process.php page:

[image]

Why is the final else statement printing on screen when Its logging in?

Comment: really, you can't figure that out by your self, the problem is there first 5 lines of your php code `$username = $_POST['username'];` and then again `$username = 'root';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `$username` and `$password` to `$uname` and `$pass` as they are conflicting with database credentials

I highlighted in the code where to make changes

```
<?php
$uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); //Change here
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); //Change here

$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'phplogin';

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Change Here
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users
            WHERE username = '".$uname."'
            AND password = '".$pass."'"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo mysqli_num_rows($result); //   I Checked to see if I was getting no rows. *I am getting 0 rows!!* But why?!

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of user
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    $dbpassword = $row['password'];

    //check to see if the match
    if($uname == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword ) { //Change Here
        echo "You're Logged In!";
    } if($uname != $dbusername || $pass != $dbpassword) { //Change Here
        echo "Incorrect password or username!";
    }

} else {
        die("That user doesn't exist!");
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

and in your HTML missing `</form>`

```
<html>

    <form action="process.php" method="POST">
        Username:   <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        Password:   <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In"><br>
    </form>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Now I realize the problem. New to programming still learn :) However, I am getting the last else statement: else {
  die("That user doesn't exist!"); on my page. Can you tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: I copied and pasted your updated code without while loop. But it still shows: "You're Logged In!That user doesn't exist!"

Comment: no it shouldn't or may b you copied the code when i was in the middle of editing, compare the code in answer and the one you copied see if they are same i put condition that `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)` check user detail else `die("That user doesn't exist!");`

Comment: It worked! I recopied your code and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just one question: What was the problem with the while loop? So I clearly understand why it was causing an issue.

Comment: lets say you wana fetch all records from specific table, `whileloop` is the solution but in case of login, you don't need to fetch all user detail, only need to check and fetch one detail, so `whileloop` is not the good choice here because it is fetching all the user detail which match username and password

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root'; //change this to another name like $db_username
$password = ''; //change this to another name like $db_password
$dbname = 'phplogin';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Please create a notepade++ dbconnection.php file and copy this code

           <?php
                mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                mysql_select_db("dabasename");
            ?>
    ----------------------------------------------------------

    Please create a notepade++ index.php file and copy this code

        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html lang="en-US">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
            <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width,initial-                      scale=1" />
            <link rel="shortcut icon" type = "image/jpg" href="images.jpg" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/bootstrap.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id = "container">
             <div id = "login_header">
              <div id = "login_text">YOur Title</div>
             </div>
             <div id = "login_content">
                <img src = "images.jpg" width = "100%" height = "150px" />
                <table width = "100%" style = "margin-top:25px;">
                    <form name = "frmLogIn" action = "login_check.php" method = "post">
                        <tr>
                            <td width = "10%"></td>
                            <td width = "20%">User Type</td>
                            <td width = "10%">:</td>
                            <td width = "50%">
                             <select name = "optUserType" class = "form-control">
                              <option></option>
                              <option>Admin</option>
                              <option>User</option>
                              <option>Guest</option>
                             </select>
                            </td>
                            <td width = "10%"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td width = "10%"></td>
                            <td width = "20%">Username</td>
                            <td width = "10%">:</td>
                            <td width = "50%"><input type = "text" name = "txtUsername" class = "form-control" /></td>
                            <td width = "10%"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width = "10%"></td>
                            <td width = "20%">Password</td>
                            <td width = "10%">:</td>
                            <td width = "50%"><input type = "password" name = "txtPassword" class = "form-control" /></td>
                            <td width = "10%"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td colspan = "5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                        <tr><td colspan = "5" align = "center"><input type = "submit" name = "btnLogIn" value = "Log In" class = "btn btn-info" style = "width:100px;"/></td></tr>
                    </form>
                </table>
             </div>
             <div id = "login_footer"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>

     -------------------------------------------------------------------
     Please create a notepade++ login_check.php file and copy this code 
    <?php
        session_start();
        require('dbconnection.php');
        if(isset($_POST['btnLogIn']))
        {
            $userType = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['optUserType']);
            $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtUsername']);
            $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtPassword']);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_user` WHERE user_type = '$userType' AND username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
            $query = mysql_query($sql);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            if(mysql_affected_rows())
            {
                $_SESSION['user_code'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
                //header('Location:home.php');
                echo "you have logged in";
            }
            else
            {
                //header('Location:home.php');
               echo "you coud not logged in!";
            }
        }
    ?>
```